# ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have this error.  I know where is problem but I can't solwe it.
I have WCF web service that is working.
I need seckond web service that is identical to first web service but it has diferent namespace. 
localhost/test1.svc
localhost/test2.svc
I don't want to add web referance so I used wsdl.exe on test1.svc?wsdl
Now I want to call with that class test2.svc but I am geting this error.
ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher
I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.endpointdispatcher.aspx)

But I am not shure how to use it. Or ise there any other way to dinamicli add web service url.

Answer (score 1):

When consuming the services, you define two different endpoints for your service:

eg

```
      <endpoint address="address1"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="test1config" contract="service.icontract"
    name="test1endpoint" />
      <endpoint address="address2"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="test2config" contract="service.icontract"
    name="test2endpoint" />
```

Then you can specify an endpoint you wish to use in your code like this:

```
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IContract>("your-endpoint-name-here");
```

and use that to create your channel in the normal way.

From that you can choose which one you use at the right time by changing the endpoint name.